# Parsing in Objective C

Tags: ios, parsing

I have a file that looks like this with multiple lines

```
1; 2;3 ;4 ;5 ;6 ;7 ;8 ;9 ;10 ;11 ;12;
1; 2;3 ;4 ;5 ;6 ;7 ;8 ;9 ;10 ;11 ;12;
```

When I go to read the line and get the components I get 13 components.
for instance
my log print out would have

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
""
```

I tried removing white space before parsing but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
line = [line stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet::[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

currently I am getting the components using

NSArray*components = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

**I don't want to just stop reading when I get to component 12. I want it to not parse anything beyond the last semicolon on the line.**

**Also I cannot just change the file and sometimes the entries are blank.**

Comment: `components = [components subarrayWithRange:(NSRange){ 0, 12 }];`?

Comment: This would be great given that the data length never changes. Although he mentions that he can't change the file, robust code would be agnostic to data length.

Comment: @random it's trivial to adjust the code and replace `12` by `components.length - 1`.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant if it was I don't think the question would have been asked.

Comment: @random OP wasn't asking the question about my comment.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the last object:

```
NSMutableArray *components = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[line componentsSeparatedByString:@";"]];

[components removeLastObject];
```

Or incase you don't know where the "" might appear:

```
NSMutableArray *components = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[line componentsSeparatedByString:@";"]];

[components removeObjectIdenticalTo:@""""];
```

Comment: that's not what his problem is. he already uses `componentsSeparatedByString:@";"` to parse individual lines. His problem is the empty entry after the last semicolon.

Comment: ah, that makes sense.

Comment: and `""` is not two quotes, it's an empty string. If you wanted to remove two quotes, the code should have said `@"\"\""`. But this still works – why, that's left to an exercise to you (hint: string literal juxtaposition is concatenation.)